# how to move a project from my personal repo to an organisation repo while preserving commits

Tags: git, github

I have a repo in my personal github which needs to be moved to an organisation's repo. I want to preserve commits while pushing to the new repo in org. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create an empty repository in your organisation, and clone it.

in this repo, add your github repository as a nex remote:

```
 git remote add githubrepo https://somewhere.on.github/project
```

then fetch it

```
 git fetch githubrepo
```

then push the github master to your organisation master (supposed to be in origin remote)

```
 git push -f origin githubrepo/master:master # you probably need to force as you rewrite the history somehow
```

this is for master, you can then push any branch you want to your origin repo